# AJAX call to ASP.NET web method returns garbage characters at end of content, but only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, google-chrome, webmethod

This is my call:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      url: location,
      data: JSON.stringify(ajaxData),
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: callback,
      error: function (x) { alert(JSON.stringify(x)) }
    });
```

The method is defined in an .aspx.vb file:

```
  <Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
  <Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Xml)>
Public Shared Function WebMethod(ByVal arg As String) As String
Dim xml As New Text.StringBuilder
Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xml, New XmlWriterSettings With {.Encoding = New Text.UTF8Encoding(False)})
'build XML and return it
End Using
End Function
```

This works as imagined in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome the error handler fires, and the responseText property of the request object contains the expected XML plus a varying number of `\u0000`s. I assume I'm messing up the encoding somehow, but I can't figure out how. This is what the end of response looks like in the Chrome visualiser:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Seems like there is some Encoding difference**, the data may be encoding differently by the server with respect to browser. Check the headers for the incoming AJAX.

Try this, set [Response.CharSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525304(v=vs.90).aspx) = "iso-8859-1" at server.
or [Response.CharSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525304(v=vs.90).aspx) = "iso-8859-13" at server.

Take a look at this blog:[Charset Encoding in ASP.NET Response](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Dec/23/Charset-Encoding-in-ASPNET-Response)